# Is it natural to say "prop the paper up against the book"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

If you put a paper on a not-so-smooth table, it is hard for you to write on it.

In that case, you might want to put the paper on something that is a bit soft and smooth like a book or a a bunch of papers.

Is it natural to say "**prop the paper up against the book to write more easily**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

*Prop the paper up against the book* is perfectly good, but it means something different. I am currently writing some music, so when I play through, I have the printed pages on the music stand on the piano, but because they are loose pages, they bend and fall over, so I **prop them up against a book**, so they stay nearly vertical.

What you want to do is to **lean the paper on a book**, or **have a book to lean on**.

(Edited after a comment from the OP. For some reason I had not thought of "lean on", which is the most fitting phrase, at least to my ears).

Comment: Can we also say "**lean the paper against the book**"?

Comment: No, _lean against_ would imply that the paper was raised, not flat on the book. But _lean on_ is actually the most familiar expression for this, and I will amend my answer.

Comment: Brits would probably say '**rest** the paper on a book'.

Comment: I'm British, and I prefer "lean on".